# It still reports an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' altought nodejs has already upgraded to v16

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I want to build a project base next13 on server. But it appears an error that my local environment doesn't appear.

```
> TTMall_Next@1.0.0 build:stag_gg
> cross-env MODE=staging_gg next build

/mnt/www/ttmall_front_next/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:347
                    ...pageKeys.app ?? [], 
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/www/ttmall_front_next/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js:10:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
[PM2] Applying action deleteProcessId on app [ttmall_front_next](ids: [ 0 ])
[PM2] [ttmall_front_next](0) ✓
```

The nullish coalescing operator was newly added in ECMAScript 2020, if I update nodejs to v14 or latest and it should has nothing problems.

And I have already check nodejs version on my server, it's v16.13.2

```
+ node -v
v16.13.2
SSH: Failed to get hostname [XXX: XXX: Name or service not known]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [XXX] ...
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [cd /mnt/www/ttmall_front_next
tar -zxf tmp.tar.gz
#nvm ls
#nvm use v14.10.0
nvm use v16.13.2
node -v
npm -v
npm install --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org
#npm install node-sass --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
#npm run build:stag
npm run build:stag_gg
#npm run build:stag_gg2
chown -R www.www /mnt/www/ttmall_front_next
/usr/local/bin/pm2 delete ttmall_front_next
/usr/local/bin/pm2  start  npm --name ttmall_front_next --error log/error.log --output log/output.log -- run start_stag_gg
] ...
Now using node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)
v16.13.2
8.1.2
```

I have already upgrade nodejs to v19.0.0, but the error stll happens.

And I have set the nodejs version to v16.13.2 in package.json.It doesn't work.

And if have use v14.10.0 everything is ok.After I upgrade to v16.13.2 or v17.0.0, the error will appear again.

Comment: `I have set the nodejs version to v16.13.2 in package.json` that doesn't make sense, you don't set a nodejs version in package.json

Comment: Can you please show the code of what you are trying to compile, you could be mis-using the `??` operator in your context of your code. Thanks!

Comment: @Alvin CHENG I didn't use `??` in my code.As you can see the error is from 
`mnt/www/ttmall_front_next/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:347`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, maybe try updating the package?

Comment: However, there could be another issue in your code where you passed `undefined` or something that the dependency's methods cannot handle, therefore the code could be throwing errors.

Comment: @Alvin CHENG So I delete all my code, but the problem still happen.And then I just use `npx create-next-app@latest` to init a project.
What is your project named? my-app
Would you like to use TypeScript? No
Would you like to use ESLint? Yes
Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? No
Would you like to use `src/` directory? Yes
Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) No
Would you like to customize the default import alias? Yes
What import alias would you like configured? @/*
And this is what I set.
And the error still appears.

Comment: Seems weird. I donno, it could be a another dependency that next depends on that could be conflicting. Honestly, I don't really know what is goinig on here, maybe try and submit a PR or issue to next. I'm sorry that I could not have helped @kratospan. Have a great day!

Comment: @Alvin CHENG OK thanks for your comment.I have already submit a PR to next.Wish you have a great day.